# dockerfile - unable to create files within /var/log

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is the command in the dockerfile -

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/f2b && chown -R root:root /var/log/f2b && touch /var/log/f2b/sql.log && touch /var/log/f2b/login.log && touch /var/log/auth.log && touch /var/log/cron.log

VOLUME /var/www/html/resources/cache /tmp /var/log/apache2 /var/log/f2b
```

Its seems to run ok

```
Step 28/58 : RUN mkdir -p /var/log/f2b && chown -R root:root /var/log/f2b && touch /var/log/f2b/sql.log && touch /var/log/f2b/log.log && touch /var/log/auth.log && touch /var/log/cron.log
 ---> Running in fb4ce5a50c63
 ---> bdff7517a17d
```

However when the image is run then -

```
ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/f2b/sql.log
```

PS - even if the VOLUME command is removed the files are not created in /var/log/f2b

Comment: Can't reproduce. Building an image from `centos:7`, containing only your `RUN` command successfully generates  folders/files in the container. Maybe you should provide your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: How do you run the container (in particular, do you mount external volumes)?

Comment: yes, docker run --mount source:target. @Henry

Comment: @leopal the issue was in the docker run command as it included a mount. As a result the source mount locations which were empty caused the problems.